# PHP email with ATTACHMENT – fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path

Tags: php, html, forms, email, email-attachments

I'm having a real hard time getting to attach any file and email the PHP form.

I'm trying to achieve a simple file attach function that emails the attachment to a specified email address. I don't want to use PHPmailer as I find it really complicated for such a little function.

I got the form from here – http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/280373-uploading-file-and-sending-as-attachment-in-e-mail/

Please help!

I'm getting these errors:

```
**Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 36
Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 37
Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 37
Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 38**
```

---

**THE HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <table width="100%" border="0" align="center">
        <tr>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
         <label for="title">Title *</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
         <select name="title">
         <option value="0">Title</option>
         <option value="1">Mr.</option>
         <option value="2">Ms.</option>
         <option value="3">Mrs.</option>
         </select></td></tr><tr><td id="ta">
          <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" required="required">
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30" required="required">
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30" required="required">
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <label for="telephone">Telephone Number *</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30" required="required">
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <label for="comments">Details</label>
         </td>
         <td valign="middle" id="ta">
          <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="100000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td valign="middle" id="ta">
         <label for="file">Or upload a file (only word, excel or pdf)</label>
        </td>
        <td valign="middle" id="ta">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center" id="ta">
          <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

---

THE PHP CODE:

```
<?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            $title = array('Title', 'Mr.', 'Ms.', 'Mrs.');
             $selected_key = $_POST['title'];
             $selected_val = $title[$_POST['title']]; 

                $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
                $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
                $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
                $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
                $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

                if(($selected_key==0))
               echo "<script> alert('Please enter your title')</script>";
             function clean_string($string) {
                  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
                  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
                }
              $email_message = "";
             $email_message .="Title: ".$selected_val."\n";
             $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
                $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

            $email_to = "bhavesh.k.2007@gmail.com"; // The email you are sending to (example)
            //$email_from = "sendfrom@email.com"; // The email you are sending from (example)
            $email_subject = "subject line"; // The Subject of the email
            $email_txt = "text body of message"; // Message that the email has in it
            $destination=$_FILES["file"]["name"];


            /**here you open the file, the $fileatt variable become a resource**/
            $fileatt = fopen($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],'r'); // Path to the file (example)
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], $destination);

            $fileatt_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; // File Type
            $fileatt_name = "Details.docx"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

            /**here you are just read the $fileatt opened**/
            $data = fread($fileatt ,filesize($fileatt));

            fclose($file);

            $semi_rand = md5(time());
            $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";
            $headers="From: $email_from"; // Who the email is from (example)
            $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
            "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
            " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
            $email_message .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $email_txt;
            $email_message .= "\n\n";
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
            "Content-Type: {$fileatt_type};\n" .
            " name=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
            $data . "\n\n" .
            "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

            mail($email_to,$email_subject,$email_message,$headers);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```html
/**
  here you open the file, the $fileatt variable become a resource
**/
$fileatt = fopen($_FILES["file"]["name"],'r'); // Path to the file (example)

$fileatt_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = "Details.docx"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

/**
  here you are trying open a resource but not a file,
  cuz $fileatt is a resource from $_FILES['file']['name']
**/
$file = fopen($fileatt,'r');
$data = fread($file,filesize($fileatt));
fclose($file);
```

try this:

```html
/**
  here you open the file, the $fileatt variable become a resource
**/
$fileatt = fopen($_FILES["file"]["name"],'r'); // Path to the file (example)

$fileatt_type = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"; // File Type
$fileatt_name = "Details.docx"; // Filename that will be used for the file as the attachment

/**
  here you are just read the $fileatt opened
**/
$data = fread($fileatt ,filesize($fileatt));

fclose($fileatt);
```

i suggest you to open the `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']`instead of `$_FILES['file']['name']`, and do it before you call the `move_uploaded_file` function.

try and tell me what

Comment: Thanks buddy... I've updated the php code above in my question as per your suggestion. However, it still doesn't work. You can try for yourself – http://www.drearth.in/email-test/test.html.

The errors: Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 46

....

Comment: i'm getting the `Internal Server Error` message

Comment: Okay... Well some good news is that it's now sending the email with attachment :-) But bad news is that the attachment comes as "Details.docx" with nothing at all :-(

Comment: it's a good news. so, can you read binary this file like this : `$fileatt = fopen($_FILES["file"]["name"],'rb');`? try and tell me what

Comment: Yeah... finally we reached somewhere :-) I updated the last suggestion but still empty "Details.docx" and the errors: 
Warning: fopen(vitamins.pdf): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 35

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 42

...

Comment: puts it as he was. removes the option rb. I can say that the problem whith the `fopen` function was solved, now it's another problem about sending mail with attachment. let me try and tell you what

Comment: for sending mail with attachment, see here: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#113161](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#113161) and here [http://www.wufoo.com/guides/how-to-send-a-file-attachment/](http://www.wufoo.com/guides/how-to-send-a-file-attachment/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["name"], $destination);
 $fileatt = fopen($_FILES["file"]["name"],'r');
```

have to be that:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
$fileatt = fopen($destination,'r');
```

because $_FILES["file"]["name"] is just the "basename" of the file
you need the file that is uploaded (in your /tmp)

Comment: Thanks Alexis... tried it but still gives me:

Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 38

Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 39

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 39

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 40

Answer (score 0):

try this:

`$fileatt = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'r');`

because it's the original file in a temp directory

Comment: Thanks Ntoprog... tried it but still gives me:  Warning: fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 38

Warning: filesize() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 39

Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 39

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /homepages/34/d565332578/htdocs/email-test/send2.php on line 40

Comment: try to do this before moving the file with `move_uploaded_file` function.

Comment: when moved the file, are you sure that the `move_uploaded_file` work? can you see that file just uploaded?

Comment: Yes, the file did upload! But it won't email :-(